# Block jupyter notebook cell execution till specific message received

Tags: python, rabbitmq, jupyter-notebook, python-asyncio, pika

I'm trying to implement asynchronous, distributed computation engine for python, which is compatible with jupyter notebook. The system is supposed to be based on 'push notification' approach what makes it (almost, I hope) impossible to allows user to wait for specific computation result (i.e. block execution of given notebook cell until message with expected result is delivered). To be precise, I'm trying to:

1. Add new task to jupyter notebook event loop (the task is periodically checking if specific msg has arrived in while loop, breaks when msg arrived)
2. Block current cell waiting for the task to be completed.
3. Still be able to process incoming messages (Using RabbitMQ, Pika, slightly modified code from http://pika.readthedocs.io/en/0.10.0/examples/asynchronous_consumer_example.html)

I have prepared notebooks presenting my problem: https://github.com/SLEEP-MAN/RabbitMQ_jupyterNotebook_asyncio

Any ideas? Is it possible (maybe some IPython/IpyKernel magic ;>?), or I have to change my approach by 180 degree?

Comment: Added a tested answer, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you mixed two different loops in one. That is why it didn't work. You need to make few changes.

Use `AsyncioConnection` instead of `TornadoConnection`

```
    return adapters.AsyncioConnection(pika.URLParameters(self._url),
                                      self.on_connection_open)
```

Next you need to remove below line

```
self._connection.ioloop.start() #throws exception but not a problem...
```

Because your loop is already started in connect. Then you need use the below code for waiting

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(wait_for_eval())
```

And now it works

[image: AsyncIO waiting]